# PowerMock throw java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock

### I am using Powermock + Mockito2 + JUnit4 to unit test a class.

When I try to run `ApiCreatorFacadeImplTest.java`, it does not work and throw `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`. I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone please point out what mistake am I making?

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({HttpUtil.class})
public class ApiCreatorFacadeImplTest {

    private ServiceVersionFacade serviceVersionFacade;
    private ServiceFacade serviceFacade;

    private ApiCreatorFacadeImpl apiCreatorService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        apiCreatorService = new ApiCreatorFacadeImpl();
        // mock ApiCreatorFacadeImpl fields
        serviceVersionFacade = mock(ServiceVersionFacade.class);
        serviceFacade = mock(ServiceFacade.class);
        // inject fields to apiCreatorService
        Whitebox.setInternalState(apiCreatorService, "serviceVersionFacade", serviceVersionFacade);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(apiCreatorService, "serviceFacade", serviceFacade);
    }

    @Test
    public void createHsfTypeApi() {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Test
    public void getApiTestParam() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

detail exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:308)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible reason is that Powermockito, Mockito's version conflict. Could you examine Powermockito, mockito's supported version. You can look 
[this page](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito).

Comment: @HomJie  I have the same error , I am using only 2 dependencies
 powermock-module-junit4 1.6.4 and powermock-api-mockito 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is due to incompatible versions of the Mockito library. You should use powermock-api-mockito in a case if you are already using Mockito 1.x and use powermock-api-mockito2 when using Mockito 2.x.

P.S. For example, if you are using Spring Boot and spring-boot-starter-test dependency then your project already includes the Mockito dependency, check the Spring Boot Parent's BOM-file (pom-file with versions of dependencies) for the version of the Mockito.